# Ordering issue with Groupby in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am facing issues in using order by with group by in linq queries. when I apply group by after order by the ordering is being lost using the following code.

I want to sort all the conversations where type is in ascending. I doubt using Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()) is creating some issue.

I am using LINQ queries like this

```
   DateTime? convStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90);
   DateTime? convEndDate = DateTime.Now;
   var limit = 1000;
   var offset = 0;

   var query = (from conversation in db.textMessagesconversation
                join msgParticipants in db.participants on conversation.Id equals msgParticipants.ConversationId
                join msg in db.MsgMessages on conversation.Id equals msg.ConversationId
                where msgParticipants.UserId == userID && ( (String.IsNullOrEmpty(convStartDate.ToString()) || msg.DateCreatedTime >= convStartDate)
                      && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(convEndDate.ToString()) || msg.DateCreatedTime <= convEndDate)
                select new RawConversation
                {
                    LastMessageContent = msg.Content,
                    LastMessageDateTime = msg.DateCreatedTime,
                    IsAttachment = msg.IsAttachment,
                    SenderId = msg.SenderId,
                    MessageId = msg.Id,
                    Type = conversation.Type,
                    Name = conversation.Name,                                        
                    Id = conversation.Id                       
                });

 query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Type);
 var textmessagesList= query.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()).Skip(offset).Take(limit).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you need the `OrderBy` after the `Select`.  Also you might need to order before the `FirstOrDefault` depending on what you want to get for each `Id`.

Comment: `GroupBy` discards order in Linq to Entities.

Comment: Since the order (`type` is orthogonal to the grouping (`id`), you mean you want to sort by type _within each group_?